# after exporting a swing project to jar file will the code get executed every time it's launched?

Tags: java, swing

I know this a simple doubt but I am just unsure about the implementation process of jar file and wondering if there might be any other way to fetch real time data.

I have a statement which determines the current date:

```
private static Date currentDate = new Date();
```

So will the currentDate get updated whenever this rendered jar file
is executed?

Comment: It will get updated every time the class is loaded.

Comment: okay but will the class get loaded everytime a new instance of the jar file is run? @RobbyCornelissen

Comment: Yes, typically the class is loaded when it is first used. Different instances of the JVM running the same JAR file will not share state with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. jar is merely a collection of all the executable class files. So every time you run a jar file, the code runs from beginning just like how it runs in your ide